what are differences between {**catch-all} and {**remainder} and {**any} in YARP path config?
I made a simple project with ASP.NET core 8 as reverse proxy. I downloaded YARP from NUGET and configured YARP in appsettings.json file. What is differences between {**catch-all} and {**remainder} and {**any} in YARP path config?
Any help will be appreciated.

I found a similar question in github which pointing to .net core route template reference. And the lateset document for .Net 8 share similar explanation.
Certainly, we can also get the result from this section. The Path configuration is an ASP.NET Core route template.
For path matching, {**catch-all} and {**remainder} and {**any} doesn't have any differences. No matter we define path as blog/{**remainder} or blog/{**catch-all} or or blog/{**any}, they will all match url blog/route1/route2. The only difference is the variable name, when we use {**remainder}, we could say the url we matched for remainder is route1/route2. If we used {**any}, we could say the url we matched for any is route1/route2. But it will be different when we set the path as {*any}. It will make the change, we could say the url we matched for any is route1%2Froute2.

Asterisk * or double asterisk **:
Can be used as a prefix to a route parameter to bind to the rest of
the URI. Are called a catch-all parameters. For example,
blog/{**slug}: Matches any URI that starts with blog/ and has any
value following it. The value following blog/ is assigned to the slug
route value.

